# Wordpress Slider Plugin that continuously rotates like a conveyor belt

Tags: wordpress, slider, carousel

I have been looking around Google and testing various WP plugins, however I cannot find one that specifically does what I need it to.

I am looking for a slider that can rotate posts, pages and/or images as a conveyor belt would do. So far the closest I can find is a one-post-in one-post-out system.

I am willing to attempt to create a slider myself but my JS knowledge is very poor. I feel as though I may just need to adjust a very small setting to achieve this, but I have hit something of a brick wall.

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
<div class="slideshow">

            <?php $thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'full' );?>
            <div class="slide first" style="background-image: url('<?php echo $thumb['0'];?>')">
                <?php the_title(); ?>
            </div>

            <?php $slideshowPosts = new WP_Query('showposts=10&orderby=rand&posts_per_page=5');
                if ($slideshowPosts -> have_posts()):
                    while ($slideshowPosts -> have_posts()) : $slideshowPosts -> the_post(); ?>
                    <!-- instruction -->

                        <?php $thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'full' );?>
                        <div class="slide rest" style="background-image: url('<?php echo $thumb['0'];?>')">
                        <?php the_title(); ?>
                        </div>

                    <!-- end instruction -->
                    <?php endwhile;
                else :
                    echo '<p>No content found</p>';
                endif; 
            wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
        </div>

.slideshow {
    height:240px;
    overflow:hidden;
    height:240px;
    width:3200px;
}
div.slide {
    height:240px;
    width:400px;
    float:left;
}
.rest {
    -webkit-animation: bannermove 30s linear infinite;
    animation-delay: 5s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
.first {
    -webkit-animation: bannermove 30s linear infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes "bannermove" {
 0% {margin-left: 0px;}
 100% {margin-left: -2125px;}
}
```

Comment: See this example https://divisoup.com/image-carousel-demo/

Comment: I found this https://jsfiddle.net/wb28eeh2/1/ very close to what I am looking for however I would like to use divs instead of images and I just cannot get it to work at all.... not sure how to post my html / css

Answer (score 1):

I always use Revolution Slider for my websites.
Its have no limits, and I'm sure you will find in it what you are looking for.

https://revolution.themepunch.com/

Comment: Thanks for your help, but looking at the link its something to pay for and I'm far too cheap for that lol. I think if i get to the point where I am pulling my hair out, I will defo give it a go!

Answer (score 1):

So im guessing you already tried https://en-au.wordpress.org/plugins/image-slider-widget/screenshots/

I think with tweats it can auto rotate.

But if your looking at js, you might find the below interesting

http://www.jqueryscript.net/slideshow/jQuery-Auto-Rotating-Image-Slider-with-CSS3-Wipe-Effect.html

Comment: Thank you this is really helpful, I have found a few methods using only css but I only just about understand how it works. I have bookmarked the JS link for a day when im ready to take that leap. I don't really like just copying and pasting if it can be avoided. I will let you know how I get on with the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Revolution slider For this. This is a awesome WordPress Slider plugin. You can create almost anything what you want.

[Click Here to View the Plugin](https://revolution.themepunch.com/)